# Why sometimes some keyboard keys don't work and other times they work?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, keyboard, interrupts

Very crazy situation here.

For a considerable time now, some of my keys don't work on the keyboard at some times[usually they are the 1-9 keys], and other thing is sometime some keys continuously keep pressing. These keys are usually either space bar or the enter.[may be others do too,and i probably don't notice it] When this happens its pretty annoying. If i'm reading a pdf it just scrolls until the end, if i'm writing a code it keeps going down the lines.

What's weird is i'm pretty sure this is nothing to do with hardware. I know this because

1. problem comes even with the usb keyboard
2. on-screen on my Windows  Education OS is the same[if some keys are not working in
   the keyboard its same with on screen keyboard]
3. I have a Ubuntu running in a virtual environment(VMWare) on windows and when i log
   into this my keyboard works fine.!

I'll be grateful if anyone has some suggestions of how to solve this. I hate to install windows and the software from scratch again and more importantly i would like to know what kind of a weird problem i'm having. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your computer keyboard, external USB keyboard and on-screen keyboard do not work correctly.

Try the following:

1. From an Admin Command Prompt, DISM and SFC.

dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /StartComponentCleanup

dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth

SFC /SCANNOW

Restart when the above is complete and test.

2. If the above fails, try repairing Windows with the Windows 10 Education DVD.

Comment: I did the 1st as you told John and i have a feeling the problem is solved now. Because usually when i restart the laptop, auto key pressing happens at login screen and it didn't happen today. I'll inform you after checking after some time if its completely gone. Thank you very much John. Sorry about being late :)  I'm from Sri Lanka so the time zones are different and i asked the question at mid night and went to sleep.

Comment: Thanks for the update - I thought something like that :)